# Bcakbone.js error in collection fetch

Tags: backbone.js, collections, fetch

I'm trying a simple backbone.js application. And getting error on doing collections fetch and not able to figure out why. Any pointers to check for will be helpful.

1- My backend is java based.

2- here are my model and collection

```
var lesson = Backbone.Model.extend
({
defaults : 
    {
        lessonId: '',
        lessonName: '',
        subject: '',
        textBook: '',
    },

    initialize: function()
    {}
   });

var lessonsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend
({
model: lesson,
url: "/lessons?subject=Math&class=5",

initialize : function(){
    //var items = this.fetch();
    //console.log(items);
}

});
```

3- The response produced from server on the data request is :

```
[
{"lessonId":"00000001","lessonName":"DemoFractions","subject":"Math","textBook":"Null"},
{"lessonId":"00000002","lessonName":"test ","subject":"Math","textBook":"test"}
]
```

4- My code to make fetch call looks like

```
var coll = new lessonsCollection();
coll.fetch(
        {
        success: function(){
           console.log("got data");
           } ,

         error: function(){
           console.log("error in getting data through rest");
           }
        }
    );
```

However everytime the fetch call is resulting in error. What is it that I'm missing in my code?

EDITED: Based on suggestion I'm now logging the response. My code looks like

```
     coll = new lessonsCollection; 
 coll.fetch(
         {    
               success: function(){
                     console.log("got data");
                     self.render() ; 
               } ,

       error: function(collection, response){
             console.log("error in getting data through rest");
             console.log("response text got ",response.responseText);
             console.log(response);
           }
         }     
        );
```

The console log appears like a js code to me.

error in getting data through rest
response text got
({readyState:0, getResponseHeader:(function (e){var t;if(2===b){if(!c){c={};while(t=Tn.exec(a))c[t[1].toLowerCase()]=t[2]}t=c[e.toLowerCase()]}return null==t?null:t}), getAllResponseHeaders:(function (){return 2===b?a:null}), setRequestHeader:(function (e,t){var n=e.toLowerCase();return b||(e=v[n]=v[n]||e,y[e]=t),this}), overrideMimeType:(function (e){return b||(p.mimeType=e),this}), statusCode:(function (e){var t;if(e)if(2>b)for(t in e)m[t]=[m[t],e[t]];else C.always(e[C.status]);return this}), abort:(function (e){var t=e||w;return u&&u.abort(t),k(0,t),this}), state:(function (){return n}), always:(function (){return i.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}), then:(function (){var e=arguments;return x.Deferred(function(n){x.each(t,function(t,o){var a=o[0],s=x.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[o[1]](function(){var e=s&&s.apply(this,arguments);e&&x.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):na+"With"})}),e=null}).promise()}), promise:(function (e){return null!=e?x.extend(e,r):r}), pipe:(function (){var e=arguments;return x.Deferred(function(n){x.each(t,function(t,o){var a=o[0],s=x.isFunction(e[t])&&e[t];i[o[1]](function(){var e=s&&s.apply(this,arguments);e&&x.isFunction(e.promise)?e.promise().done(n.resolve).fail(n.reject).progress(n.notify):na+"With"})}),e=null}).promise()}), done:(function (){if(l){var t=l.length;(function i(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||l.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=l.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}), fail:(function (){if(l){var t=l.length;(function i(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||l.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=l.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}), progress:(function (){if(l){var t=l.length;(function i(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||l.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=l.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}), complete:(function (){if(l){var t=l.length;(function i(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||l.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=l.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}), success:(function (){if(l){var t=l.length;(function i(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||l.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=l.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}), error:(function (){if(l){var t=l.length;(function i(t){x.each(t,function(t,n){var r=x.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||l.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=l.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}), responseText:"", status:0, statusText:"error"})

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, the specific error you are getting back in the response would be really helpful for us to see, but you need at least to set `idAttribute` on your `Lesson` model.

```
var Lesson = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: 'lessonId',
  defaults: {
    lessonId: '',
    lessonName: '',
    subject: '',
    textBook: ''
  }
});
```

See if that fixes it. Otherwise, log the response:

```
   error: function(collection, response){
     console.log("error in getting data through rest", response);
   }
```

Comment: I made changes as you suggested [updated my question above]. The logs appears to be js code.

Comment: Well, it looks like the back end is not responding with a 200 OK response and a JSON response body, which is what is needed. Check with your backend developers. A little tough to debug this issue over stackoverflow.